# How to bring expensive db operation outside synchronized block safely to avoid contention

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My requirement is as below

1. To maintain a global thread safe cache so that all write should be thread safe.
2. The cache should have a expire time.
3. When the cache expires it should flush the cache data into database But also make sure that while flushing no data should be written to cache .

So the cache write operation can performed by multiple threads concurrently  however flushCache to db should happen by 1 tread periodicaly (every 1 second) .Below is my implementation

```
 static Map<String, Long> cacheTimer = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
 static Map<String,  Date> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Date>();
private Map<String, Object> bucketTimeUpdatedLockMap  = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();


     public void updateCacheLastDequeuedTime(String queueName,
            int bucketId, Date lastDequeued, boolean force) {

//Below is non-expensive cache write opration        
        String queueBucketId = queueName + bucketId;       
        // If the cache structures don't exist yet, set them up.
        if (!cacheTimer.containsKey(queueBucketId)
                || !cache.containsKey(queueBucketId)) {
            log.debug(
                    "Setting up bucketmapPendingLastDequeuedWrites cache for queue {}",
                    queueName);
            cacheTimer.putIfAbsent(queueBucketId,0L);
            cache.putIfAbsent(queueBucketId, new Date());
        }

        if (!cache.containsKey(queueBucketId)) {
            cache.put(queueBucketId,lastDequeued);
        } else {

            Date tempDate = cache.get(queueBucketId);
            if (tempDate != null && tempDate.equals(lastDequeued)) {
                cache.put(queueBucketId,
                        QueueServiceUtils.incrementDateByMilliSeconds(
                                lastDequeued, 1));
            } else {
                cache.put(queueBucketId,lastDequeued);
            }
        }

//Below is cache expensive flush operation
        if (force
                || System.currentTimeMillis()
                        - cacheTimer
                                .get(queueBucketId) > 1000)) {
            flushCache(queueName, bucketId);
        }
    }

 private void flushCache(String queueName, int bucketId) {
        String queuebucketId = queueName + bucketId;
        Object bucketTimeUpdatedLock = getBucketTimeUpdatedLock(queuebucketId); //taking a lock over an object 
        synchronized(bucketTimeUpdatedLock){ 
        //rechecking
            if (cacheTimer.containsKey(queuebucketId) && System.currentTimeMillis()
                    - cacheTimer.get(queuebucketId) > 1000)){    

        // why setting timer here? To keep a track when the last time this cache got flushed      
        cacheTimer.put(queuebucketId,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (cache.containsKey(queuebucketId)
                && cache.get(queuebucketId) != null) {
                Date lastDequeuedTime = cache.get(queuebucketId);
                //below is an expensive operation.
                queueServiceMetaDao.updateLastDequed(lastDequeuedTime, queueName, bucketId);
                cache.remove(queuebucketId); //reset cache
                }

            }
        }
    }
    //THis method will help in lock splitting instead of taking lock on queue take lock on bucket of queue (1 queue has 100 buckets)
    private Object getBucketTimeUpdatedLock(String queueName) {
        Object readBucketAssignLock = bucketTimeUpdatedLockMap.get(queueName);
        if (readBucketAssignLock == null) {
            log.debug(
                    "getting bucketTimeUpdatedLock for newly created queue {}",
                    queueName);
            Object lock = new Object();
            readBucketAssignLock = bucketTimeUpdatedLockMap.putIfAbsent(
                    queueName, lock);
            if (readBucketAssignLock == null)
                readBucketAssignLock = lock;
        }
        return readBucketAssignLock;
    }
```

Below are my queries :

1.My above implementaion does not full fill the 3rd requirement " make sure that while flushing no data should be written to cache ."

2. How to bring my db operation outside synchronized block safely .
3. Should I use ReentrantReadWriteLock  instead of synchronized block ? as I will have parallel writecache operations  (15-50 per second so assign read lock?) however only 1 flush operation (assign write lock?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly consider using a [Guava `Cache`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) with time-based expiration and, if it's truly a requirement to prevent entries from being written to the cache while flushing to the database, use a synchronous removal listener.

Consider whether the synchronous listener is absolutely necessary though, as it could significantly slow down the performance of the cache.

From the documentation:

> **Warning:** removal listener operations are executed synchronously by
>   default, and since cache maintenance is normally performed during
>   normal cache operations, expensive removal listeners can slow down
>   normal cache function! If you have an expensive removal listener, use
>   RemovalListeners.asynchronous(RemovalListener, Executor) to decorate a
>   RemovalListener to operate asynchronously.

For more details, see https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.